# Получение списка файлов по маске Linux\C

Tags: c, сортировка, фильтры, файлы, linux

Пару дней назад начал изучать С. Столкнулся со следующей задачей:
Дано:
Папка с файлами разного содержания (.jpg, .pdf, .txt и. т. д.)
Задача:
получить на выходе что-то типа

```
jonik@jonik-Inspiron-3521:~/Изображения$ ls *.jpg *.gif
12f0908s-480.jpg
973780671.jpg
howprog.gif
```

для работы с каталогами нашел, в этих наших интернетах, конструкцию типа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;

    char directory[255] = "./";
    dir = opendir(directory);

    while ((ent=readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", ent->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе имеем все содержимое паки
Основной вопрос:
Каким способом отфильтровать вывод данного кода по маске *.jpg *.gif?

Comment: man 3 glob
    man 7 glob

Comment: Посмотрите `man fnmatch`.

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментариев:

например, можно воспользоваться функциями `glob()` или `fnmatch()`.

описание и примеры есть в соответствующих man-страницах:

```
$ man 3 glog
$ man 3 fnmatch
```